# Pusher disconnect & timeout

Tags: pusher

will my server be notified about disconnect on the client side?
I assume the answer is yes if the disconnect happens explictly like below.

```
pusher.disconnect()
```

however what happens if the user simply closes the browser?

Another thing is there a way to notify the server that a certain channel has not been in use by the client(s) for some while?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [connection states documentation](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/connection/#connection-states) shows how to bind to connection state changes.

> however what happens if the user simply closes the browser?

This really depends on if the browser calls `webSocketInstance.onclose` so the Pusher JavaScript library is informed before the browser is closed. You could always detect this yourself using `window.onbeforeunload`, `window.onunload` or the `addEventListener` versions.

> Another thing is there a way to notify the server that a certain channel has not been in use by the client(s) for some while?

You can use [WebHooks](http://pusher.com/docs/webhooks) so that when a channel becomes vacated your app server will be informed.